# Image capture opens after iPhone is connected

Tags: iphone, mac

Everytime I connect my iPhone to my laptop, Image Capture opens. How to I stop it? I just need to use iTunes, not Image Capture.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The preferences you are looking for are **located in Image Capture itself**.

Here is what to do:

[image]

Comment: In case some people can't find this option, try clicking the little triangle in a square icon in the bottom left, as it may be hiding the option.

Comment: There are no devices listed.

Comment: In my case I needed to select the device first, otherwise no menu appears

Comment: Wow, is this still the best way to do this? It seems like an "iOS devices" preference pane in System Preferences next to the other hardware pref. panes would be a *much* more intuitive way to handle this.

Comment: Because really, doesn't his answer answers the question, "Where is the one place on my Mac where I control which application opens after my iPhone is connected?"?

Answer (score 3):

You can select `Other...` and then `iTunes` from the drop down menu below `Connecting this iPhone opens`.  [image: Select No application]

Answer (score 2):

Open iTunes/Preferences with your iPhone connected and check:

[image]

And also check in iPhoto's preferences and select "No Application":

[image]

Comment: now both iTune and Image Capture opens. How can I disable auto open Image Capture?

Comment: Tell iPhoto to Not open anything, did you try that?

Comment: KMC, the correct answer is the one provided by Matt below.