# Set Image Capture to launch when I connect my mobile

Tags: macos, image-capture

In the past, when I connected my mobile, Image Capture launched. I have an Android device.

At some point, I disabled this feature and now I need to set it back.

Unfortunately, I am not able to find how to do it.

I am on El Capitan 10.11.5

I have checked Photos but couldn't see any settings to change the default app.

So, what happens now is that I connect the device, I launch ImageCapture and it doesn't recognise the mobile.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/32575/2841), the setting is in Image Capture itself. Note, however, that the option won't show up in the bottom left corner until you actually connect your phone.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I should clarify. Now Image Capture doesn't recognise the mobile so, as you mention, I can't see this option.

Comment: @JohnKouraklis Try opening the Image Capture manually after connecting the device.

Comment: @ShineethHamza That's what I do. It doesn't recognise the device. I am very annoyed with Apple. They have messed up all their software

Comment: @JohnKouraklis Is iTunes detecting your device? else it will be a problem with your cable.

Comment: @ShineethHamza I have an android device. Should itunes detect it?

Comment: @JohnKouraklis My bad. No if you have an android phone, it won't detect in iTunes. I was in an impression that it's an apple product. And of course please include that (the device model and OS version) in your question. It might help others to tweak the issue fast. By the way are you able to see the disk in finder when you connect the device? if not please check the USB setting in ur device.

Comment: @ShineethHamza I should have mentioned this. I updated the question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you set a [system setting to disable all hot-plug events](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211212/5472), you might need to remove those settings specifically or generally:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.ImageCapture disableHotPlug -bool NO
```

or to just clear that key in the preferences

```
defaults -currentHost delete com.apple.ImageCapture disableHotPlug
```

At that point, you should be able to go into Image Capture with the device connected and toggle the settings. I wonder if you have a connection issue if you don't see the device in ImageCapture - it should show up there once you have trusted the computer from the iOS device. I suppose that missing trust could also be the root cause.

To troubleshoot that, iTunes is a better option. Start here and if you can't see the device, there is a follow on article covering the ways to regain connection:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203060

Comment: This must be the right approach but after searching my system I don't have such file which means that terminal can't alter the property. I get this error message:

2016-07-14 17:06:32.727 defaults[56553:4582570] 
Domain (com.apple.ImageCapture) not found.
Defaults have not been changed.

Comment: @JohnKouraklis that's a good error - deleting something that's not there means you don't have that suppressing the pop up. It's then either lack of trust from iOS or a failure to communicate.